# android activity and service

Tags: android

is it ok to create a class which extends a service within a class that extends an activity

public class fill extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seconds);
               ....................

}


public class MyCount extends Servcie{
       .................................
        ..................................
       .................................
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do:

- You need only an inner class? Than create one inside another class. (what you didn't have done because `MyCount` is not inside the `Activity` class)
- You need another class but it shouldnt be an inner class? Than create a new file for this class.